# Build Polymer App with multiple elements using one single Dart script

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Do you know how to use multiple "polymer-element" with only one Dart script ?

I succeeded but I am not sure it is the best solution.

My example is a **Dart/Polymer** implementation of this following example with **Dart/WebUI**:
https://www.dartlang.org/articles/web-ui/#loops

It displays a list of fruits in a polymer-element ("**example-template1**"), and where we can research a specific fruit in another polymer-element ("**example-template2**"). The second polymer-element must update the first with data binding.

To do that, I declared as follow my polymer elements. One parent polymer-element named "**example-script**" (because we can only use one script declaration in a polymer templates file), and children that extend from this parent :

```html
<polymer-element name="example-script">
  <script type="application/dart" src="tute.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="example-template1" extends="example-script">
  <template>
    <div>
      <p>Search fruit</p>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ research }}" on-input="{{ get_results }}">
    </div>
  </template>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="example-template2" extends="example-script">
  <template>
    <div><ul>
      <template repeat="{{ fruit in fruits }}">
        <li>{{ fruit }}</li>
      </template>
    </ul></div>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

My Dart script is as follow:

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'dart:html';

@CustomTag('example-script')
class FruitsScript extends PolymerElement {
  static List<String> fruitsList = new List();

  @observable static List<String> fruits = toObservable(fruitsList);
  @observable static String research = '';

  FruitsScript.created() : super.created();
}

@CustomTag('example-template1')
class FruitsResearch extends FruitsScript {
  FruitsResearch.created() : super.created();

  String get research {
    return FruitsScript.research;
  }

  String set research(String search) {
    FruitsScript.research = search;
  }

  void get_results(Event e, var detail, Node target) {
    FruitsScript.fruits.clear();

    if (FruitsScript.research.length > 0) {
      var lResearch = FruitsScript.research.toLowerCase();
      var results = FruitsScript.fruitsList.where((v) => v.toLowerCase().contains(lResearch));
      FruitsScript.fruits.addAll(results);
    }
    else {
      FruitsScript.fruits.addAll(FruitsScript.fruitsList);
    }
  }
}

@CustomTag('example-template2')
class FruitsDisplay extends FruitsScript {
  FruitsDisplay.created() : super.created() {
    List<String> fruits = [ 'Apple', 'Apricot', 'Avocado'];

    FruitsScript.fruitsList.clear();
    FruitsScript.fruitsList.addAll(fruits);
    FruitsScript.fruitsList.sort();
    FruitsScript.fruits.clear();
    FruitsScript.fruits.addAll(FruitsScript.fruitsList);
  }

  List<String> get fruits {
    return FruitsScript.fruits;
  }
}
```

I declare one parent Class "**FruitsScript**" to initialize the observable variables. Then, I create two other classes for my two polymer elements "**example-template1/2**". Hence I can access to my observable variables. But for that, I also need to declare them as **static**, and to make **setters** an **getters** in my subclasses, otherwise my polymer elements can not share the observable variables.

This method works, but do you think there is a better way to make this?

Comment: I am curious why you would want to use only one script.

Comment: I use only one script to be able to share my observable variables between my multiple polymer elements. Hence, I want that data binding on one element (example-template1) updates the other element (example-template2). But maybe I am on the wrong way; I am a newcomer in the Polymer world :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you add those elements to your page?
As far as I understand what you want to to, inheritance (extend) is not the appropriate solution.
I have not tried to run this code just edited your code here in the textfield.
If this is what you want to do but something doesn't work post a comment.
I didn't want to put to much time in it as long as it's not clear what exactly you want to achieve.

In your web page you lay out your elements like this:

```html
<example-template1></example-template1>
<example-template2></example-template2>
<example-script></example-script>
```

Your elements

```dart
<polymer-element name="example-script">
  <script type="application/dart" src="tute.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="example-template1">
  <template>
    <div>
      <p>Search fruit</p>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ model.research }}" on-input="{{ get_results }}">
    </div>
  </template>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="example-template2">
  <template>
    <div><ul>
      <template repeat="{{ fruit in model.fruits }}">
        <li>{{ fruit }}</li>
      </template>
    </ul></div>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Your Dart script is as follow:

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'dart:html';

class Model extends Object with Observable {
  @observable List<String> fruits = toObservable(new List<String>());
  @observable String research = '';
}

@CustomTag('example-script')
class FruitsScript extends PolymerElement {
  @published Model model = new Model();

  FruitsScript.created() : super.created();

  void attached() {
    super.attached();
    (document.querySelector('example-template1') as FruitsResearch).model = model;
    (document.querySelector('example-template2') as FruitsDisplay).model = model;
  }
}

@CustomTag('example-template1')
class FruitsResearch extends PolymerElement {
  FruitsResearch.created() : super.created();

  @published Model model;

  void get_results(Event e, var detail, Node target) {
    if (this.research.length > 0) {
      var lResearch = this.model.research.toLowerCase();
      var results = this.model.fruits.where((v) => v.toLowerCase().contains(lResearch));
      this.model.fruits = toObservable(results);
    }
  }
}

@CustomTag('example-template2')
class FruitsDisplay extends PolymerElement {
  @published Model model = new Model();

  FruitsDisplay.created() : super.created() {
    this.model.fruits = toObservable([ 'Apple', 'Apricot', 'Avocado']);
    this.model.fruits.sort();
  }
}
```

Comment: In fact, I want to be able to use multiple polymer elements that share the same observable variables. Moreover, I want to be able to put these elements on several locations in my HTML page. For example, with publishing attibutes, I have to put my two sub-elements within the parent-element to share the observable variables. But I don't want this.

Comment: Because if I made like this, I have to put a lot of my HTML code in a "polymer" template file. As I use another templating framework to display my HTML pages (jinja2), I can't do this. This is why I want to define my HTML pages with jinja2, and then insert within my polymer elements defined in Polymer's templates.

Comment: I have updated the code according to your added requirements. You can also remove the example-script element entirely and move the code from enteredView to e.g. main() or some function with @initScript.

Comment: Thanks for the solution: that is working! I edited your code to reflect the one I tried and which is OK. I use "static" attributes instead of "(document.querySelector("skills-display") as SkillsDisplay).model = model;" in the "enteredView" method, because Dart shows me a warning otherwise. Thanks a lot ;) Your solution is prettier than my first try :)

Comment: When you use a static field (as in your edit) the <example-script> element is redundant. You don't need an element to hold a static field.